# Wrapping Text Around Figures Doesnt Work ...[Latex - Miktex ]

Tags: latex

so i have a problem , i want to put a figure inside some text , which means wrapping text around this pic .

but its not working  instead , its just showing the pic at the buttom left side of the enxt page

The problem is in the figure name : Jule_bel

**image to eshow the problem** ----->  [image]

**Here is my code :**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}
\textit{République Algérienne Démocratique et Populaire 
\newline
Ministère de l'Enseignement Supérieur et de la Recherche Scientifique 
\newline
Université des sciences et Technologie Houarie Boumediene.}
\newline
\\
\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{USTHB}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\begin{Large} 
\center 
\bf \center \hspace{0.5cm} Faculté Des Mathématiques 
\newline
Département de Recherche
Opérationnelle.
\end{Large}

\vspace{1.8cm}

\begin{huge}
\center \bf \textit{Rappot de Stage}

\end{huge} 

\vspace{3cm}
 \begin{large}
 \center Année 2020-2021
 \end{large}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}
 
 \newpage
 
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter*{Remerciements}
 
 \flushleft

\hspace{0.3cm} \textbf{ Je tiens a remercier toutes les personnes qui ont contribué au succès de mon stage et qui m'ont aidé lors de la rédaction de ce rapport. Je tiens a remercier vivement mon encadreur, responsable Projets Supply Chain au sein de l'entreprise Bel Algérie, pour son accueil, le temps passé ensemble et le partage de son entreprise au quotidien. Gr\^ ace aussi a sa confiance j'ai pu m'accomplir totalement dans mes missions. Elle fut d'une aide précieuse dans les moments les plus délicats.\\
\hspace{0.3cm} Je remercie également toute l'équipe de cette entreprise pour leur accueil, leur esprit d'équipe et en particulier M.Bentaiba, qui m'a beaucoup conseillé. }




\chapter{Présentation de l'entreprise Bel Algérie}
\section{Qui est Bel}

\vspace{0.5cm}
\hspace{0.5cm} 
\vspace{0.5cm} La société de Fromageries Bel est une entreprise de
l'industrie agroalimentaire 
\vspace{0.5cm}
ayant son siége en région \^Ile-deFrance. Les \'etablissements Jules Bel ont été fondés en 1865 Orgelet à (Jura).\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
\hspace{0.5 cm}  Les marques commerciales de cette société sont distribuéees dans les 5 continents. Elle est implantée dans plus de 30 pays. Ses fabrictions sont commercialisées dans plus de 120 pays.
Chauque jour, plus de 33 millions de portions de fromages Bel sont consommées dans le monde.

%---------------------------------------------------------------



\section{Historique de l'entreprise} 

 \hspace{0.3cm} Pour comprendre ce qui fait la 
personalité de Bel, rien de tel que de se plonger dans son histoire.
Ou comment une fromagerie du Jura est devenue un Groupe international tout en conservant son audace et sa bonne humeur.

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.25\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{jule_bel}
    \end{center}
   \caption{Jules Bel}
\end{wrapfigure}

a

\hspace{0.3cm} C'est en 1865 que Jules Bel installe dans le Jura, son commerce d'anage et de négoce de comté. Aprés son décès en 1904, son ls Léon Bel reprend l'a aire.



 Au lendemain de la première guerre mondiale, l'industrie naissante du frommage prend son essord et Léon Bel pressent le potentiel du frommage fondu, bon, économique,facile à transporter et à conserver.Il se lance alors dans l'avenue industrielle et fonde en 1922 la société des fromageries Bel.\\
 

 
%---------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
En 1921, Léon dépose la marque La Vache qui rit, un produit absolument nouveau en France à l4époque, tant par sa recette originale.

 
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{les coulisses de la saga bel}
\caption{les coulisses de la saga bel}
\end{figure}
 


\section{Histoire de la filiale Bel Algérie}

L'histoire de la filiale Bel Algérie est:
\begin{description}
\item[2001] Création de la structure légale algérienne.
\item[2002] Création de la filiale Algérienne phase de sou-traitance locale.
\item[2005] Lancement de chantier de la 1ére usine Bel à Kolea.
\item[2007] Commercialisation de 1er fromage en portion La Vache Qui Rit produit localement à l'usine de Koléa.
\item[2018] Plus de 1000 emplois directs et 600 emplois indirects. \\
Aujourd'hui le marché algérien LEADER mondial de consommation "la vache qui rit".
\end{description}



\chapter{Le cadre de stage}
\section{Direction et organigrammes de Bel Algérie}
Les directions de l'entreprise Bel Algérie sont:
\\
\begin{itemize}
\item Direction de l'Administration et Finance.
\item Direction générale.
\item Direction de Roussources Humaines.
\item Direction Usine.
\item Direction Commerciale.
\item Direction Suplly Chain.
\item Direction Marketing.
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Je suis ici:}
La direction de Supply Chain se compose de :
\begin{enumerate}
\item Director Supply Chain.
\item Responsable Supply Chain Usine.
\item Preformance and Project Manager Supply Chain.
\item Demand planner and activity Manger.
\item Responsable des opérations. 
\item Responsable de l'import.
\item Responsable Service Client.
\end{enumerate}
La logistique chez Bel algérie assure: 
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$\diamond$]La gestion des importations et des approvisionnements.
\item[*] La gestion de stock et des entrep\^ots.
\item[\textbullet] Le transport et la distribution.
\item[$\diamond$] La gestion des retours ou reverse loistics.
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\begin{flushright}
\section{Apports du stage:}
 Au cours de se stage, j'ai beaucoup appris. Les apports que j'ai tiré de cette expérience professionnelle peuvent \^etre regroupés autour de trois idées principales : les compétences acquises, les difficultés et solutions apportées ainsi que la vie en société.
\subsection{Compétences acquises}
\`A Bel Algérie, j'ai pu connaitre à quoi semble la vie professionnelle, j'ai compris comment elle fonctionne chaque entreprise à l'intérieur, en plus j'ai appris plusieurs nouvelles notions comme VBA et la maitrise de l'Excel. 
\subsection{Difficultés rencontrés et solutions apportées}
Durant mon stage je n'ai pas rencontré de problèmes gr\^ace à Bel Algérie qui fournit tous les besoins de chaque individu dans son intégration. Cependant, j'ai rencontré quelques difficultés dans mon travail sur des connaissances que je n'avais pas et que j'ai pu développer au cours de mon stage.
\end{flushright}

 
 \chapter*{Conclusion}
 \hspace{0.3cm} Ce stage a été, sous plusieurs aspects, riche en enseignements. Le stage consistait à rééaliser une automatisation de fichiers afin le travail. Il m'a permis d'améliorer mes connaissances en Excel et d'acquérirune nouvelle connaissance en programmation VBA.
 \\
 \vspace{0.3cm} 
 \hspace{0.3cm}
 A l'heure actuelle, l'application est pr\^ete à \^etre utilisée. On peut donc conclure que le but qui m'avait été fixé a été atteint. Le contact avec le monde de l'entreprise m'a permis de progresser dans de nombreux domaines, notamment sur le thème de Supply chain.
 \\
 \vspace{0.3cm}
 \hspace{0.3cm}  
 EN CONCLUSION MON STAGE M4A PERMIS DE METTRE EN OEUVRE DES COMP\'ETENCES SCOLAIRES, PROFESSIONNELLES ET HUMAINES POUR UN SUJET INT\'ERESSANT. J'AI DE PLUS AQUIS DE NOUVELLES COMP\'ETENCES DANS LE DOMAINE DU MANAGEMENT DE LA CHAINE LOGISTIQUE.
 
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the

```
\flushleft
```

This conflicts with `wrapfigure` and `wrapfigure` tells you this in the `.log` file. Either remove this or don't use `wrapfigure`.

---

Unrelated to this problem, there are more syntax errors than I can count. Just to name a few:

- don't use the `center` environment inside other environments like `figure`, this will add additional vertical space. Use `\centering` instead
- Don't use manual formatting inside your text, this is a clear sign that you use latex incorrectly. Instead of cluttering your document with `\vspace` and `\hspace` change the parindent for the whole document
- don't manually use `\\`, `\newline` etc. If you want to start a new paragraph, leave an empty line in the code and let latex do what it can best: format your document for you
- don't use vertical spaces inside of paragraphs, these won't be inserted where you think they are and will destroy the line spacing (same for font size changes)
- don't use two letter font commands like `\bf`
- font size changes are switches and should be used like

  ```
   {\Large some text}

   empty line before text in another size
  ```

  They are NOT environments
- `\center` is not what you think it is. Use `\centering` instead
- use the `description` environment instead of manually formatting your list
- the `francais` babel option is deprecated
- many other problems ...